# Invalid flag as not a real question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed, not-a-real-question

How is this question "not a real question"?

[Sort HTML attributes with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752904/sort-html-attributes-with-javascript/13753851#comment18905939_13753851)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, playing devil's advocate, the original question lacks some code or structure of how are your working and the relation between the JS desired code and the HTML.

Do you wanted to do it "inside" the same page or the JavaScript is being executed somewhere else and taking a file and transforming it. With the rising use of JavaScript in the server you could have both possibilities.

But I think most people is bothered by the lack of a previous attempt since it feels like a "Gimme the codez!" kind of question.

Comment: But that doesn't make it not a real question.

Comment: "This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, **overly broad**, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form."  This is exceptionally true of the original revision.  As it is now, with subsequent edits that add context and ask answerable questions, it's reopenable.